# Chinese characters appear garbled when Adobe Illustrator opens a PDF created using reportlab

Tags: reportlab, adobe-illustrator

I used reportlab to create a pdf file that contains a Chinese text. I have registered the Chinese font file. There is no problem when the pdf is opened directly through the browser, and the Chinese text is displayed normally.
[Opend by brower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnc4I.jpg)

However, when it is opened using Adobe Illustrator, the Chinese text is garbled. I don't know why.
[Opend by Adobe Illustrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TzQT.jpg)

````
```python

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics

from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('SimSun', 'SimSun.ttf'))



c = canvas.Canvas('output.pdf')

c.setFont('SimSun', 12)

c.drawString(100, 100, '水果超级大卖场') 

c.save()

```
````

I hope that Chinese can be displayed normally in Adobe Illustrator

Comment: Illustrator is infamous for how it's not good at handling embedded fonts in PDF (especially if the PDF file hasn't been generated by some Adobe app). It's a common trouble. Try to install the font `SimSun.ttf` in your system. It sometimes helps. The most solid variant would be to convert all the fonts inside the PDF into 'curves' (vector graphics). I don't know if your python lib is able to do it. And of course you can't edit outlined text.

Comment: i wolud also like to convert text to curves , but reportlab doesn't provide that feature

Comment: we need to customize various fonts

Comment: Alas. I don't know the actual answer. I'd try to figure out a workaround with some JS-script for Illustrator, that would find the problem lines within opened PDF and fixed them somehow (probably it will need some extra data outside the PDF file). It's a clumsy solution of course.

Answer (score 0):

### Embedded font subsets are not supposed to be usable fonts

Frankly most vector applications struggle with embedded fonts when opening a pdf in an editable mode.

The main reason why pdf embedded font subsets don't work in most applications – it's also intended to **prevent font piracy**.
Keep in mind Adobe is also a font distributor. If a pdf containing long copy text set in a licensed – maybe rather expensive – fonts could easily be "ripped".

But you can instead create a new document - using the same document size as the pdf and import the file via **place** operation.

You get an uneditable object frame showing the pdf as it is.

Then you can use the **flatten transparency** option to include the external file in your new document.

Check **Convert all text to outlines** option to convert all text elements to paths.

[image: flatten transparency]

#### Alternative: open in inkscape

Inkscape provides an option to convert text to paths in the opening dialog

[image: inkscape]